# React Native Android keyboard dismisses instantly when user taps on textInput

Tags: keyboard, react-native, textinput

Keyboard dismisses instantly when users tap on textInput

I have several screens containing textInput, but this only happens in one of them and only happens on Android platform.

The script I show is simple because I deleted all the other codes in order to test just the keyboard and textInput and the error is still there. However, I paste the same code of this script alone in a new project and it works fine.

Hope you can help me.

```
  <View>
  <Text>NAME</Text>
  <TextInput
    style={{
      paddingVertical: 0,
      textAlignVertical: 'center',
      height: 30,
      width: 60,
      fontSize: 30,
      color: '#E1E1F2',
      borderBottomWidth: 1,
      borderBottomColor: '#6B778A',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    }}
    // onChangeText={(text => this.setState({ nameInput: text }))}
    // value={this.state.nameInput}
    placeholderTextColor={'#6B778A'}
    underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
    enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true} 
    />
    </View>
```

Expected behavior:

Don't hide the keyboard when the user taps on textInput

Actual behavior:

When the user taps on an textInput the keyboard shows up but dismiss instantly and I've been tested all my plugins separately but could find the reason.

[Screen record here](https://media.giphy.com/media/j0vi2w2zusuH8Tj8FT/giphy.gif)

[Full script in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzFy1.png)

Comment: This looks fine, can you post the full component?

Comment: `enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true} `, this might be the issue. Have you tried removing this?

Comment: @RohitKashyap yes, I did, but it didn't work.

Comment: i tested your code in this snack and it works without any problem.
https://snack.expo.io/@batreza/18efcb
could you be more clear about it please?

Comment: @Mr.Ghamkhar I've shown the full script. Yes, if I run this page of code separately, it works fine. However, when I run the entire app, the problem appears. This is strange.

Comment: Maybe your problem is happening in Redux. What are you doing there?

Comment: @hongdevelop yes, you are right. The problem comes from Redux.